# Why was Armory and Blockchain wallet removed from bitcoin.org?

Tags: wallet, bitcoin.org

I would like to learn from other's mistakes and avoid problems in the future. The page which shows available wallets is https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blockchain.info has suffered from numerous security vulnerabilities, some of which are discussed here:

https://github.com/bitcoin-dot-org/bitcoin.org/pull/663

Wallet listing criteria can be founds here:

https://github.com/bitcoin-dot-org/bitcoin.org#wallets

The reasons for Armory removal are explained here:

"Armory is no longer developed by ATI. Its website, bitcoinarmory.com, is down and is no longer Armory's website. The source code is now maintained by goatpig."

https://github.com/bitcoin-dot-org/bitcoin.org/pull/1235

A new pull request to bring it back is now open:

https://github.com/bitcoin-dot-org/bitcoin.org/pull/1301

the resolution timetable remains unclear:

"goatpig commented 5 days ago

@ABISprotocol I don't control bitcoinarmory.com, that belongs to ATI. Their current policy (I believe) with that domain is to offer binaries for the code they fully own, i.e. 0.93.x versions of Armory.

You could say the current state of affairs is that ATI tolerates my fork (and me using their trademark), but have yet to make a definitive move in either embracing it or opposing it (in which case I'd have to rebrand)."

Comment: Blockchain.info is an online wallet and just like any other online wallet shouldn't be used to store a large amount or for long term purposes. For ease of usage and small amounts their wallet is fine. The entire Bitcoin landscape has become very political and some services are demonized or removed based on their stance on the infamous blocksize debate.

Comment: Note that blockchain.info was removed in december 2014, long before many of those political arguments came into play.